# How to unchecked a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input class=checked-val type="checkbox" value="foo" checked="true" /> 
<input class=checked-val type="checkbox" value="bar" checked="true" />
```

Initially both checkbox are checked. But When I click any checkbox its checked value should be changed to checked=false. How can I do it using jquery or javascript?

Comment: I believe the checked attribute should be `checked='checked'`

Comment: When you uncheck the checkbox, it's checked value is going to be false in any case.

Comment: Why do you think the checked value doesn't change?

Comment: @Tim Down, yeah if it's HTML and not XHTML definitely

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the attribute "checked".

```
$("#selector").removeAttr("checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the checkbox will check/uncheck anyway when a user clicks on it, but if you want to do it programatically:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('cb_foo').checked = true;
  document.getElementById('cb_bar').checked = true;
</script>

<input class=checked-val type="checkbox" id="cb_foo" value="foo" checked="true" /> 
<input class=checked-val type="checkbox" id="cb_bar" value="bar" checked="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('.checked-val').removeAttr('checked');
```

Please note the syntax of your input must be:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="..." name="..." class="checked-val" checked="checked" />
```

The mechanic behind the check are:

- With `checked="checked"`, checkbox active and posted by the form submit
- Without attribute `checked`, checkbox not selected and **not posted** by the form submit

Answer (score 0):

> Initially both checkbox are checked.
>   But When I click any checkbox its
>   checked value should be changed to
>   checked=false. How can I do it using
>   jquery or javascript?

If you want this to happen you can `.one()` which attaches an event handler that only fires once.  Combine that with the other items you can simply uncheck both boxes.

```
$(".checked-val").one("click", function(){
    $(".checked-val").removeAttr("checked");
});
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/Bewjf/).**